# Datepicker not highlighting today

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like `today` to be highlighted on the UI-Bootstrap date picker. On the UI-Bootstrap demo page the Datepicker example shows a different CSS class on today's date:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I can't seem to get today to highlight separately from the selected day. I have created a Plunker here,

http://plnkr.co/edit/JCcWQhvLcERssg56pQUA

Answer (score 0):

You should call `$scope.today()` in your controller. This way, your `StartDate` will get today's value and therefore will be highlighted.
see [edited Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WFxWXNbIpEUcy22bcS23?p=preview)

Comment: Yes I can highlight today by calling `$scope.today()`, but I need to: "get today to highlight separately from the selected day." As per the example page.

Comment: check out the javascript on the example page. that's exactly what they do.

Comment: This is exactly what's copied into the example Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JCcWQhvLcERssg56pQUA

Comment: this is the exact example from the documentation: http://plnkr.co/edit/rFDppVnWqfvOr17c9uhL?p=preview. look at example.js. it calls `today()` right after its definition

Comment: Calling today() is not the answer this only selects the current day and doesn't highlight it permanently.

Comment: OK, I see the problem. If you change the version of UI-Bootstrap to `0.10.0` it no longer highlights today's date. I am using version `0.10.0`.